# boost asio find beginning of message in tcp based protocol

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, protocols, boost-asio

I want to implement a client for a sensor that sends data over tcp and uses the following protocol:

1. the message-header starts with the byte-sequence `0xAFFEC0CC2` of type `uint32`
2. the header in total is 24 Bytes long (including the start sequence) and contains the size in bytes of the message-body as a `uint32`
3. the message-body is sent directly after the header and not terminated by a demimiter

Currently, I got the following code (assume a connected socket exists)

```
typedef unsigned char byte;

boost::system::error_code error;
boost::asio::streambuf buf;
std::string magic_word_s = {static_cast<char>(0xAF), static_cast<char>(0xFE),
static_cast<char>(0xC0), static_cast<char>(0xC2)};

ssize_t n = boost::asio::read_until(socket_, buf, magic_word_s, error);
if(error)
   std::cerr << boost::system::system_error(error).what() << std::endl;
buf.consume(n);
n = boost::asio::read(socket_, buf, boost::asio::transfer_exactly(20);

const byte * p = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const byte>(buf.data());
uint32_t size_of_body = *((byte*)p);
```

unfortunately the [documentation for read_until](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read_until/overload3.html#boost_asio.reference.read_until.overload3.remarks) remarks:

> After a successful read_until operation, the streambuf may contain additional data beyond the delimiter. An application will typically leave that data in the streambuf for a subsequent read_until operation to examine.

which means that I loose synchronization with the described protocol.
Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Well... as it says... you just "leave" it in the object, or temporary store it in another, and handle the whole message (below called 'packet') if it is complete.

I have a similar approach in one of my projects. I'll explain a little how I did it, that should give you a rough idea how you can handle the packets correctly.

In my Read-Handler (-callback) I keep checking if the packet is complete. The meta-data information (header for you) is temporary stored in a map associated with the remote-partner (map<RemoteAddress, InfoStructure>).

For example it can look like this:

```
4 byte identifier
4 byte message-length
n byte message
```

Handle incoming data, check if identifier + message-length are received already, continue to check if message-data is completed with received data.
Leave rest of the packet in the temporary buffer, erase old data.
Continue with handling when next packet arrives or check if received data completes next packet already...

This approach may sound a little slow, but I get even with SSL 10MB/s+ on a slow machine.
Without SSL much higher transfer-rates are possible.

With this approach, you may also take a look into [read_some](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload2.html) or its [asynchronous](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_read_some.html) version.